# RagGrid paging asp.net

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

I am using a Radgrid which shows data from a table having more than 50,000 rows. But i am using paging and shows only 25 rows at a time. how can i make the grid to read only 25 rows from the database table at a time rather than all the rows, and also allow filtering for all the data.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/182395-custom-paging.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Telerik's custom paging as explained in the link in the comments.

You need to change your query for binding the grid data to fetch just the rows of the current page. This is my suggestion for doing it:

Pass CurrentPageIndex (zero based) and PageSize as parameters to the database query. you can then get the data for the page like this:

```
With MyResult AS
(
    select ..., rank() OVER (partition BY ... ORDER BY ...) AS RankOfRow
)
select * from MyResult 
where RankOfRow > PageIndex * PageSize 
and RankOfRow <= (PageIndex + 1) * PageSize
```